# Assistance needed figuring out how to construct a simple game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with my homework. I am in an immersive Full Stack Development course. We are making a game, with two characters (side by side, in their own containers). There is supposed to be an "Attack" button that can be clicked, and an "Energy" counter that counts down by 20. Once the opponent's Energy hits 0, "GAME OVER" is supposed to be displayed. I am stuck and struggling. Can one of you more experienced developers please help me so I will not fail my class? I will include the link to the code (that I have so far).

[enter link description here](https://github.com/DarneshaJ/CR)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your source files, it appears you have lots of syntax errors both in your HTML and JavaScript. I don't even see the call to your `script.js` in your `index.html`.

I suggest re-reviewing the material for your own benefit. Part of becoming a successful developer is having a solid grasp on the fundamentals.

Comment: I would love to,but we never went over materials on how to make this game. That's why I came here for help. Everyone else in the class has experience and has completed the assignment. I have zero experience. I have tried google, and that is where the majority of my "code", if it can be called that, came from. Can you help me? If yes, cool and thanks so much. If no, I understand and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, off the bat I can see in your script you have `if (energy<==0)`

This should be `if (energy<=0)`

What bit are you stuck on though? It's a little hard to gauge where you are when some basics have been missed, such as the `script.js` not even referenced in your `index.html`